# Can I take note or highlight on paper during a TOEIC test in the reading section?

Tags: terminology

I heard that I cannot take notes during the listening section of the test (correct me if I am wrong) but I am wondering if similar rules apply to the reading section. Can I take notes or highlight texts in the reading section?

Comment: The authority for this is the testing service itself.

Comment: Thanks for down voting, I just wanted to ask this question but I couldn't find a suitable Stackexchange site to ask it. But do I really deserve a downvote?

Comment: I did not downvote but voted to close as Off Topic. I suspect some people may have downvoted because there was no evidence of research - it took me less than 30 seconds to find the answer.

Comment: Notice that in the case of questions closed as off-topic, one down-vote is automatically done. No user is involved in that down-vote, which means that only a user down-voted the question, now that its score is -2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the TOEIC [User Guide](http://www.ets.org/Media/Tests/Test_of_English_for_International_Communication/TOEIC_User_Gd.pdf), page 5, **Test Center Procedures**

> - Books, dictionaries, papers, notes, rulers, calculators, watch alarms, mobile phones, listening devices, recording or photographic equipment, highlighters or aids of any kind are not allowed in the testing room.
> - Paper of any kind is not permitted in the testing room.
> - Test takers may not mark or underline words in the test book or make notes in the test book or on the answer sheet.

That would seem to rule out any note-taking during any portion of the test, since you are not permitted to mark the materials provided and are not permitted to bring in anything else on which notes could be taken.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I've been preparing for the reading section by highlighting keywords and I wished if it is possible during the actual exam too =(..